# Puppet master agent configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet

I am getting error in puppet agent test:

```
parallels@puppet-server:~$ puppet agent -t
Error: Could not request certificate: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
parallels@puppet-server:~$ sudo puppet agent -t
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: /File[/var/cache/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

MASTER CONF FILE: `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[main]
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
logdir = /var/log/puppet
localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
classfile = $vardir/classes.txt
[master]
environment = production
server = puppet-server
ca_server = puppet-server
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
cadir  = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca
dns_alt_names = puppet
```

MASTER `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.64.14  puppet-server 
192.168.64.16  node-01
```

AGENT CONF FILE: `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[main]
ssldir = /var/lib/puppet/ssl
vardir = /var/lib/puppet
cadir  = /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca
dns_alt_names = puppet

[agent]
server=192.168.64.14
ca_server=192.168.64.14
```

AGENT `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   parallels-Parallels-Virtual-Platform
192.168.64.14  puppet-server                                   
192.168.64.16  node-01

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says:

> Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

It cannot find the host `puppet`.

If you add that to `/etc/hosts` on your client and server, it should work:

```
192.168.64.14  puppet
```

Comment: Still same issue . I changed /etc/hosts of agent  and changed puppet-server to puppet .

Comment: Please also update `/etc/hosts` on the server (edited my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you run `puppet agent -t` as a non-root user, Puppet creates a configuration folder structure under ~/.puppetlabs and ignores /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/* (source: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/dirs_confdir.html, you can pick your version from the drop-down if you're not using the latest)

If you can, try running as root (`sudo -i` first, then run `puppet agent -t`) or try with sudo (which does not work for me, but may for you).

Answer (score 0):

check if you open port 8140.
telnet puppet-server 8140

Answer (score 0):

In my VM, the IP address changed, so changing the **/etc/hosts** file by adding the following at the end solved the issue.

```
192.168.0.7 puppet-master puppet-master.local
192.168.0.8 puppet-client puppet-client.local
192.168.0.7 puppet puppet.local
```

Here puppet-master is the name of the puppet server system and puppet-client is the hostname of puppet-agent system